# Django Forms in Modal not rendering

Tags: django, modal-dialog

i am trying to get my form to render in a Modal, however the modal show up empty. the form is not rendering in the modal, i am using function base view and not class based view. i have also tried Django-Bootstrap-Modal-Forms but it didnt work with me at all so i reverted to the code below method

Model:

```
     class Startup ( models.Model ) :
         author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
         startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

     class Startup_About ( models.Model ) :
         str_about = models.ForeignKey ( Startup , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
         about = models.TextField ( 'About Startup' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
         problem = models.TextField ( 'Problem/Opportunity' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
         business_model = models.TextField ( 'Business Monitization Model' , max_length = 2000 , null = False ,blank = False )
         offer = models.TextField ( 'Offer to Investors' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
```

View:

```
     def create_startupaboutform(request) :
         stup = Startup.objects.filter(author=request.user)
         if request.method == 'POST' :
             form = startupaboutform ( request.POST )
             if form.is_valid ( ) :
                 instance = form.save ( commit = False )
                 instance.str_about = stup
                 instance.save ( )
                 return redirect ( 'str_detailedview' )
         else :
             form = startupaboutform ( )
         return render ( request , 'create_about.html' , { 'form' : form } )
```

Forms:

```
    class startupaboutform(forms.ModelForm):
         class Meta:
             model = Startup_About
             fields = ('about','problem','business_model','offer',)
             widgets = {
                 'about' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
                 'problem' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
                 'business_model' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
                 'offer' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
    }
```

Home HTML:

```
     {% load static %}
     <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
               content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    </head>
    <body>



    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</a>

    {% include "create_about.html" with form = form %}

     <script>
     $(".btn").click(function(){
         $("#about").modal("show");
         $(".modal-content").load("{% url 'create_startupaboutform' %}");
     });
     </script>

    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

MODAL HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="about" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form action="{% url 'create_startupaboutform' %}" method="post" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">About Startup</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{form}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have amended my HTML to triger the modal with JQUERY however the modal does not render correctly and no contant is there

Comment: i have solved the issue of rendering the form through Jquery however the model is not showing properly only the form input fields are showing up, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by adding the Jquery to trigger button/link and load the form as following, remember that the Jquery code to be placed in the same page as the trigger button/link is:

```
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#id of the trigger button").on("click", function(){
                 $("#form id surrounding the Modal").load("/Django Route ex. add_new", function(){
                 $("#Modal ID").modal("show");
             });
             });
     });
     </script>
```

ensure to add the include tag in the same page of the trigger button or link:

```
     {% include "route to the HTML containing the modal" %}
```

put your modal in a new HTML as following:

```
     <form id="about-form">
         <div class="modal fade" id="about" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
             <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                         <label>About Startup</label>
                         {{form.about}}
                    </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </form>
```